# Have there been UNSC attempts to force the US forces out of Syria? What were the results?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, syria, unsc

Clearly forcing the US forces out of Syria will fail at the UNSC due to US veto. But that hasn't stopped such attempts in other conflicts, i.e. countries still advance resolutions that they know they'll fail, just "for the record" and sometimes to showcase the diplomatic isolation of a P5 member in a certain case. Recent examples would include [the referendums held by Russia in Ukraine](https://press.un.org/en/2022/sc15046.doc.htm) etc.

Has anything like that been attempted with respect to US forces in Syria? Russia and Syria protest this presence. But have they done that at the UNSC? What were the results of the vote(s)?

Answer (score 2):

One would guess not.  Last time Syria is mentioned in Security Council quick meetings lists was [in 2014](https://research.un.org/en/docs/sc/quick/meetings/2014) and neither case was about booting out the US.

Now, mind you, embarrassing another P5 cuts both ways:  if it's your resolution that gets overwhelmingly shot down, rather than failing via P5 veto, you're embarrassed instead.

(And Europe has so many Syrian refugee problems that they'd probably be very quick to nuke anything giving the Syrian government a freer hand in oppressing its citizens, something a US exit might facilitate).

A Google search for `syria un security council resolution -242 "veto"` lists mostly vetos by Russia/China on behalf of the Syrian government.

Also nothing on Wiki's [list of vetoed UN resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vetoed_United_Nations_Security_Council_resolutions).  Almost all the vetoed ones are Russia + China.

Comment: Wow, that long ago. The proverbial "nothing to see, move along".

Comment: Not sure that listing is too good though because I found a passed one in 2015 http://unscr.com/en/resolutions/2254 that does mention Syria.

Comment: Good point.  I was looking for "Syria" in the listings, but this one is, like many, many, "The situation in the Middle East".

Comment: This https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/un_documents_type/security-council-resolutions/?ctype=Syria&cbtype=syria albeit unofficial seems to be better index. However, it only lists resolutions that passed the vote, so no useful in this case.