# Have there been any UNGA votes regarding the US presence in Syria?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, united-nations, syria, unga

Relating to a couple of other questions here: it appears that while Russia and Syria object to the US presence in Syria, they've not brought up the case at UNSC even for pure protest purposes. However, as we recently saw in the case of Israel-Hamas, getting UNGA votes for some [non-binding] resolution is easier than getting something through UNSC (past vetoes).

So, did Russia, Syria, or anyone else raise the matter of US presence in Syria at the UNGA, and if so what were the results?

N.B. a quick search [finds](https://apnews.com/article/islamic-state-group-united-nations-general-assembly-syria-civil-wars-dc70194fc4ff4b07823d3496eb0c5b7a) Syrian declarations at the UN on the matter (paraphrased there as "Syria’s top diplomat called for a U.S.-led military coalition to get out of his country [...]  Mekdad said the coalition’s presence contradicts international law and “should end immediately, without conditions.”". They also ask for  $107 billion in compensation.) I'm asking if any attempts to pass a UNGA resolution happened in this regard, e.g. to condemn the US or to refer the case to ICJ for an advisory opinion at least.

Comment: Links to related Qs: [UNSC attempts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82109/have-there-been-unsc-attempts-to-force-the-us-forces-out-of-syria-what-were-the); [US stated reasons](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/on-what-grounds-do-the-usa-affiliated-forces-and-citizens-reside-in-syria-if-syr); [international law perspectives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82100/is-the-presence-of-the-us-forces-in-syria-contradictory-to-un-charter-articles-2/82108).

Comment: Russia or China do not do anything irrational, they know that any resolution they propose that is against the strategies of the US or the regime will be vetoed by the US and its aliases. Note that there is an unwritten rule that if you propose too many unsuccessful resolutions, you will lose your authority among other countries.

Comment: @C.F.G: there's no veto at the UNGA. And is zero too many?